# Dictionary search engine by pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I'm looking for some word search engine that would allow me to search words by their pronunciation. For instance, I want a list of words beginning with "ge", but pronounced as in "get" and ignoring ones like  "Germany" or "gear".

Comment: Do you know the IPA?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for [resources](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to the question asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/online-tools-to-look-up-words-from-pronunciation). You should check the answers there.